# will my computer support a 16TB HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, dell-vostro

I currently have 2x 3TB HDD's plugged into a Dell Vostro 420 (2.72TB according to Windows) and was thinking about upgrading them to 2x [16TB HDDs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SGGWYC1).

My question is...  will that computer support them? I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate on this computer currently. I can upgrade to Windows 10 but I just haven't yet.

(the drives would be Dynamic Disk mirrors of one another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will that computer support them?

The `Dell Vostro 420` absolutely will support them as storage drives.  Your system can support GPT storage drives.  Your system is unable to boot to GPT since it does not support UEFI.  The maximum partition size for an MBR drive is approximately 2 TB

If you were to use either of these drives as a system drive, the maximum partition would be approximately 2 TB, the rest of the drive would be unallocated.

> I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate on this computer currently. I can upgrade to Windows 10 but I just haven't yet

Windows 7 and Windows 10 support for GPT storage devices are identical.
.

Comment: My previous system for years was running on a disk larger than 2 TB, but was MBR so it was limited to just under 2 TB, due to it being an image of an older system.

Answer (score -1):

According to my research, the Dell Vostro 420 comes with a non-UEFI BIOS,
and therefore cannot support GPT disks, even though the Intel Core 2 CPU
is 64-bit.

GPT is required for such large disks, as MBR can only use as much space as
you are already using on your current disks.

My answer is therefore negative: You cannot use disks of this size.

Comment: BIOS doesn't support *booting* from GPT disks, there's nothing against using them for storage.

Comment: ...at least since Windows Vista. (In Windows XP days, _all_ GPT disk support was gated behind EFI support, but that's no longer true for any modern Windows release.)

Comment: (Besides, OP currently has two _3TB_ disks, which is already beyond the MBR limit for 512b-sector disks.)

Comment: This answer is partially incorrect. The author could use the 16 TB drive for storage, they would be unable to use more than approximately 2 TB due to MBR limitations, if they were to use it for a system drive. Their system absolutely supports GPT on storage drives, due to the fact, Windows 7 and Windows 10 supports it. (This is a repost of my previous comment due to getting the value incorrect the first time)